# How do you realign array data in comparison to another array when the index is out of sync?

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement, indexing

I've created a "Choose your Case" game using a cash prize array of all the prize amounts and the case numbers a user can pick. When they pick a number, it tells the user what is in their case. However, at the end it spits out all the cases and what was in each one, and the data is misaligned by one index.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] cashPrizeArray = new int[26] { 0, 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 500, 750, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 25000, 50000, 75000, 100000, 200000 };
        int[] caseArray = new int[26] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26 };
        Array.Sort(cashPrizeArray);

        Random rnd = new Random();
        int[] cashPrizeArrayR = cashPrizeArray.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
        foreach (int i in cashPrizeArrayR)
        {
            Console.Write("{0} ", i);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n(please ignore the numbers above)\n\n\nDeal or Not!");
        Console.Write("Choose a case: 1-26: ");
        int userCase = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (!caseArray.Contains(userCase))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nUnexpected input text.\nThis application will now be terminated.\nPress ENTER to continue...");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You chose case " + userCase);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("This case contains...\n$" + cashPrizeArrayR[userCase]);
        Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("\nFor reference, below are the case numbers and their values: ");
        Console.ReadLine();
        var caseAndPrize = cashPrizeArrayR.Zip(caseArray, (p, c) => new { Prize = p, Case = c });
        foreach (var pc in caseAndPrize)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Case " + pc.Case + " $" + (pc.Prize));
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

It runs fine, but it outputs the value incorrectly, as if the data column is shifted downwards. Can anyone provide a solution where I have gone wrong? Many thanks.

[image: here]

Comment: the index is zero based

Comment: You might want to look into using classes or structs, to bring the values together into *one* array, then you won't have a chance of anything going out of sync since you're moving all the data that belongs together, together.

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
Console.WriteLine("This case contains...\n$" + cashPrizeArrayR[userCase]);
```

to this:

```
Console.WriteLine("This case contains...\n$" + cashPrizeArrayR[userCase - 1]);
```

**further suggestion**:

replace this:

```
int userCase = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

with

```
bool validKey = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var userCase);

if (!validKey|| !caseArray.Contains(userCase))
{ 
    // <snipped>
```

Comment: the index is zero based so you need to account for that.

Comment: you should also harden up this line: `int userCase = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` as it will throw an exception if the user simply presses the enter key

Answer (score 0):

cashPrizeArrayR[userCase] selects based on index. Have you considered to use instead of int[] a KeyValuePair or an Dictionary?